# How can I add multiple labels for simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am using the ruby gem simple_form for different forms for my project.

`users.date_of_birth`: type is `date` in DB.

The code below will generate three select fields and one label tag.
Is it possible to generate three labels corresponding to the select fields?

```
<%= 
  f.input :date_of_birth,
    start_year: 1900,
    end_year: Date.today.year,
    order: [:year, :month, :day],
    label: 'year'
%>
```

==== I added ====

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju4wo.png)

please see above image.

I want to display the text with label as shown.

Comment: why u need three labels?

Comment: My question is what are the thee labels name?

Comment: Also, can you show how you the UI will look like? Maybe I can tell an alternative solution

Comment: I want to display `Birth year`, `Month`, `Day`. Above each select tag.

Comment: But you only have one select tag

Comment: Are there multiple select tags? Also, add the mockup for the clarity

Comment: I update my question. plz check.